# Как создать мини документацию собственного кода?

Tags: swift, xcode

Например в модели моего пользователя есть переменная `fullName`:

```
var fullName: String {
    return firstName + " " + lastName
}
```

Я хочу установить небольшое описание того, что лежит в этой переменной в тот момент когда я вызываю это поле у модели.

Как на скрине снизу:

[image]

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте перед переменной описание после ///, например:

```
/// Description
var fullName: String {
    return firstName + " " + lastName
}
```